# How do you catch a fatal error in PHP output from a Perl client?

Tags: php, perl, httprequest

Given a perl client which is making requests to a webserver using [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) as in:

```
$request    = new HTTP::Request('POST', $someurl);
$response   = $ua->request($request);
```

we are trying to catch/trap fatal runtime errors that might be produced by PHP scripts that run out of memory or time. As an example:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted 
  (tried to allocate xx bytes) in /xxx/xxx.php on line xx
```

If the call is made from a browser, the PHP error message ends up at the end of the page and is visible in the document source and DOM:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted 
  (tried to allocate xx bytes) in <b>/xxx/xxx.php</b> on line <b>xx</b><br />
```

But when analyzing the call's $response in perl, the error message is not visible in neither the output of [$response->content](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#$r-%3Econtent) or [$response->as_string](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#$r-%3Eas_string). The stream basically 'cuts off' just before the error message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade, close
Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 07:40:52 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Server: Apache/2.4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Client-Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 07:42:25 GMT
Client-Peer: xxxx
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: xxxx
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /CN=www.xxxx.ch
Client-SSL-Cipher: xxxx
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Set-Cookie: sid=xxxxxx; path=/
Title: xxxxxxx

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>xxxxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="xxxx">
  <div id="xxxx"><img src="xxxx"></div>
    <div id="xxxx"><div id="xxxx">xxxx</div>
      <div id="xxxx">
          <div id="xxxx">
                <b>stream</b>
                marker 1
                marker 2
                marker 3
                marker 4
                marker 5
```

The problem is that all status codes or error flags (see [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response))  look ok, since the response started streaming properly.

Can someone elaborate on how to catch these kind of errors from within [HTTP:Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) or [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response)?

Comment: HTTP status code is 200 if the response started streaming correctly. The problem arises with uncatched runtime errors (memory, timeout) within PHP.

Comment: Whether error messages end up in the output of a PHP script can be controlled by ini directives. A fatal error cannot be caught, the script will shut down, but with register_shutdown_function() you can do something before it happens.

Comment: Correct, if we had a influence on the server / PHP script we'd change that. We are only in control of the client. I thought that was implicitely clear.

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of `$response->as_string()` after removing any private data?

Comment: As a debugging help, take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere. If you install that and load it anywhere in your code, it'll dump loads of useful debugging information that you can then [edit] into the question.

Comment: Also could it be that the website actually does more things? There could be an AJAX request, and the response of that might be added to the DOM at run time by the browser. LWP wouldn't do that.

Comment: Re "*But when analyzing the call's $response in perl, the error message is not visible in the output ($response->content).*", So your first order of business is finding out how to get PHP to provide the error message when the client is LWP as opposed to different browser. Is the error even happening? If it is, why is PHP handling it different when the request comes from LWP?

Comment: We just built a testcase with a PHP script that overflows the mem on purpose. There is only one output stream (no AJAX etc) and no difference in the output from the server side between connections from browser(s) vs perl and http/s. It could be, that the final error message ends up in <stderr> of the $request which might not be reflected in $response.